# SQL Server : concatenation of two tables

Tags: sql-server

How can I concatenate the values from the two tables in SQL Server?

Example:

Table 1 - two columns

```
ID        Description 
---------------------
123       Apple
123       Grapes 
123       Pear
```

Table 2 - one column

```
Remarks
-----------
Rotten
```

Concatenation result:

```
Apple-Rotten
Grapes-Rotten
Pear-Rotten
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include in your question the things you already tried to solve your problem. Otherwise it looks like you just want someone to do your homework.

But to your question:

Since there seems to be no relation between the tables, I think what you're looking for is a cross join:

`select concat(t1.description, '-', t2.remarks) from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2;`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The code works perfectly but I’m getting 3 identical records, same result with the previous code I’ve made Select concat(table1.description,table2.remarks) as Results from table1,table2 where ID=123 ,maybe I need to group the alias Results?  But it doesn’t work. I’m stuck with here. Result: Apple-Rotten
Apple-Rotten
Apple-Rotten
Grapes-Rotten
Grapes-Rotten
Grapes-Rotten
Pear-Rotten
Pear-Rotten
Pear-Rotten

Comment: Then I assume you have 3 records in Table 2, right? Quick solution would be to use `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicate rows, e.g. `select distinct concat(table1.description, table2.remarks) as Results from ...` but this would just work around your flawed database model. If there is really one entry in Table 2 for each entry in Table 1, then there should be a relation between the two.

Comment: There’s only one record in Table 2 which I want to concatenate to all records in Table 1 (3 records). Say Los Angeles-California San Francisco-California Sacramento-California, can I do group? I’ve tried but it doesn’t work if it involves two tables.

Comment: I get what you want to achieve but the result you described (duplicate rows) is not possible if Table 1 contains three records and Table 2 only one. Do a `select * from ...` on each table and double check that they contain what you think they do. You can use `group by` - it doesn't matter how many tables are involved. It's unnecessary, though, because `distinct` would yield the same result in this case and is easier to use.